# Upgrade to 23.04 from 22.10 failed with error for linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic. How do I fix?

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, 23.04

I have 22.10 running on a Dell laptop, received a popup to upgrade to 23.04. During the installation I got an error message stating that the installation of linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic has failed due to an error. At the end it said that the system will be left in an unstable state. I have not restarted the laptop, but I believe it wont restart if I tried! :/

Here is the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`:

```
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-20-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.2.0-20-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.12.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.2.0.20.20); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (6.2.0-20.20) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-20-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.2.0-20-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/build/include KVERSION=6.2.0-20-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.12.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.12.0/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, going in for a restart now! After I recovered from the initial panic, I saw the error was due to the package "evdi" missing in binaries. After googling a little, I found that this is a dependency of the "DisplayLink" driver, which evidently isn't ready for 23.04 yet. The version of evdi, 1.12 still seems to be unstable. Anyway, so, uninstalling DisplayLink driver and then running dpkg configure seems to have helped the upgrade go through.

For anyone else facing this:

1. Do not upgrade to 23.04 (yet) if you are using DisplayLink
2. Use these commands if you are stuck with this:

```
sudo displaylink-installer uninstall
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Update: OS update seems to have gone through, restart was uneventful. Now, will find a way to install Displaylink back.

Comment: You will have to install version 5.7 of the displaylink driver for it to work.

Comment: While that is true, somehow fixing this before the machine restarts for any reason was my priority then.

Comment: I understand that, and I am glad you did post the answer as I had not realized that displaylink was the culprit when I encountered the same problem and almost reverted the upgrade (I always use lvm snapshots prior to an upgrade on machines I rely for work on). Just wanted to pointout that indeed there is a working displaylink driver for the Kernel in the latest ubuntu release (This has not always been the case in the past).

Comment: Thank you! I had exactly the same problem and the steps you mentioned fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved the issue:

1. Download the latest version of displaylink from here
   [Synaptic website](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu)
   The version is 5.7.0-61.129
   (This version has this in the release notes: Added preliminary support for kernel 6.2; Added preliminary support for Ubuntu 23.04)
2. Go to the folder where the downloaded file is and unzip

   `unzip DisplayLink\ USB\ Graphics\ Software\ for\ Ubuntu5.7-EXE.zip`
3. Make the script executable

   `chmod +x displaylink-driver-5.7.0-61.129.run`
4. Run the script as super user

   `sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.7.0-61.129.run`
5. Now, reconfigure the kernel

   `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

No more errors (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

I got an error on my desktop that the kernel could not install, and it kernel panic at reboot, I was able to use the prior kernel and all good, my laptop upgraded fine but did state that a few things were in read only, but the computer locked up, I reverted back to prior kernel all seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia:

1. Boot with the prior kernel
2. Change the graphic device driver to the X.Org X server
3. Reboot with the 6.2 kernel
4. Reinstall the graphic driver - nvidia-driver-525
5. Change the graphic device driver to nvidia-driver-525
6. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and fixed it using @NikhilWanpal's solution to uninstall DisplayLink. To reinstall it, I followed the link @MicheleZ posted to Synaptics' website. But, rather than following their instructions to download the standalone installer, I used the Synaptics APT Repository. It worked immediately with 23.04 (not even a reboot required). It has the benefit of being kept automatically up to date going forward.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the 6.2 kernel install got completely broken after the upgrade, uninstalling the DisplayLink using `sudo displaylink-installer uninstall` din't resolve the DKMS compilation error. Rebooting into the 6.2 kernel would result in a kernel panic.

I eventually managed to solve that by booting into the previous kernel (`5.19.0-41`), purging the `evdi` package (`sudo apt purge evdi`), then removing the `evdi` DKMS module:

```bash
$ dkms status
evdi/1.10.1: added
nvidia/525.105.17, 5.19.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/525.105.17, 6.2.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed

$ sudo dkms remove evdi/1.10.1
Module evdi 1.10.1 is not installed for kernel 5.19.0-41-generic (x86_64). Skipping...
Module evdi 1.10.1 is not built for kernel 5.19.0-41-generic (x86_64). Skipping...
Deleting module evdi-1.10.1 completely from the DKMS tree.
```

After that the 6.2 kernel package was finally successfully configured and I could boot into it.