# Kernel Panic after upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04

Tags: 22.10, 23.04

After using the common way of upgrading via GNOME desktop I got an error msg, that the kernel and/or header files could not get installed.

When restarting the machine It tries to start with 23.04 which fails and outputs a kernel panic.

```
/dev/root: Can't open blockdev 
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mountroot fs on unknown-block(0,0) 
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu
```

When I choose to boot with the old kernel (5.19) everything works.

Any idea how I can restart the whole upgrade process or do a full downgrade back to 22.10 or 22.04LTS? Thanks in advance :)

Some infos on the machine:

- Fujitsu Lifebook U7511
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.19.0-40-generic
- CPU:
  11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 @ 8x 4,2GHz
- GPU: Iris Xe Graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling `displaylink` version 5.7.0.61 solved my problem.

[Synaptics Displaylink Driver Download](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu)

I performed `$ sudo displaylink-installer uninstall`, restarted and then reinstalled with

```
$ sudo chmod +x displaylink-driver-5.7.0-61.129.run
$ sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.7.0-61.129.run
```

I did a `$ sudo apt install && sudo apt upgrade` afterwards and the error was fixed.

Found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1464554/1087722

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem. The dkms module evid-dkms for displaylink blocked the kernel module build during installation. After uninstalling

```
sudo dkms remove evdi/1.11.0 --all
```

and upgrading agian

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

the kernel module we're built and the error is gone.

Comment: Thanks Robert, this has resolved my issue too, although I had to modify it. After first running `sudo apt upgrade` to see why it was failing, it mentioned evdi version 5.2.14, so I was surprised to see 1.11.0 in your command. Anyway, I ran `sudo dkms remove evdi/5.2.14 --all`, and after doing that the upgrade worked fine. (I had also previously tried removing the other installed version, 1.9.0 that I found in /var/lib/dkms/evdi, as the make.log file for this module was showing errors, but it didn't resolve the issue).

Comment: This would be better as an answer not a comment to an answer. You did something different therefore a different answer.